# Filtrar arquivo específico para não excluir

Tags: c#, .net, arquivo

Como fazer o código não apagar um arquivo específico que eu quero entre os  `.exe` que eu pego. Exemplo: quero que ele não apague "teste.exe", mas que ainda continue apagando todo o resto.

Segue o código:

```
string[] arquivos = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp\ae", "*.exe", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
foreach (string arquivo in arquivos)
{
    //nome = Path.GetFileName(arquivo);
    File.Delete(arquivo);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
foreach (var arquivo in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp\ae", "*.exe", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) {
    if (Path.GetFileName(arquivo) != "teste.exe") File.Delete(arquivo);
}
```

Se preferir pode fazer com LINQ, eu faria, porque é mais performático neste caso. Fazendo certo apesar de ter um pouco de *overhead* pela infraestrutura do LINQ ele faz apenas um *loop*. Na resposta do Barbetta ele faz 2 *loops*, um pra pegar os arquivos e outro para filtrar. O `Enumerate` não executa *loop* algum.

```
foreach (var arquivo in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\temp\ae", "*.exe", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Where(f => Path.GetFileName(f) != "teste.exe") File.Delete(arquivo);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/FilterFiles.cs).

Comment: i) As vezes queria ter a opção de +5 para suas respostas; ii) As vezes ficamos preocupados em fazer um código mais legível(digo isso no sentido de passo a passo) que acabamos dando voltas e voltas e "gastando" mais do que deveria.

Comment: Só não te dei +1 pq a primeira é consideravelmente menos eficiente que o segundo, e pode induzir alguém ao erro

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar um condicional dentro do próprio foreach, assim:

```
    string[] arquivos = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp\ae", "*.exe", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    foreach (string arquivo in arquivos)
    {
        var nome = Path.GetFileName(arquivo);
        if (nome != "teste.exe")
            File.Delete(arquivo);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Segue mais uma opção utilizando `linq`

```
string[] arquivos = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\temp\ae", "*.exe", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Where(p => p != "teste.exe").ToArray();
foreach (string arquivo in arquivos)
    File.Delete(arquivo);
```